# How to use JavaScript to get all element from a dynamic scroll list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, single-page-application, puppeteer

**Like the title said, how do I get all elements from a scroll div?** **The elements in the scroll list are loaded and destroyed dynamically.**

I tried to crawl all course names from this website:
https://public.enroll.wisc.edu/search?term=1204

The code below only works for one time:

```
let list = document.getElementsByClassName('md-virtual-repeat-scroller')[0]
let childs = document.getElementsByClassName("result__name")
console.log(childs[0].innerText)
```

However, if I do this, I will get the same result for 10 times:

```
let list = document.getElementsByClassName('md-virtual-repeat-scroller')[0]
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let childs = document.getElementsByClassName("result__name")
    for(let j = 0; j < childs.length; j++) {
        console.log(childs[j].innerText) 
    }
    // scroll by 1000px every time
    list.scrollBy(0, 1000) 
}
```

I don't know what's the problem. Is it because that **scrollBy()** works **asynchronously**? But I tried to use async and await. It still doesn't work.

Comment: `console.log(childs[0].innerText)` Did you mean `console.log(childs[i].innerText)`? With `[0]`, yes, you will get the same result every time, because you're accessing the same element

Comment: well, but the list is scrolled, so even childs[0] will be different since it is a dynamic list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by reading this article:https://intoli.com/blog/scrape-infinite-scroll/

The reason why I kept getting the same elements is that scrollBy() works asynchronously, so I have to wait then evaluate the page again. I am using puppeteer by the way.

please read the article, super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Give more information in less words as a possible. Many problems could be related to browser and its version, for example. How is this script called? Are you giving commands via browser console? Have you done a copy of the site and performed some modification on it? It's hard to understand the problem in a realistic level.

Tip: Avoiding use *innerText*. It's slower and is supported in many browsers only for compability to scripts written to old versions of IE. (I don't know why so many examples in internet use it as first option). User *textContent* instead.

It's always good to test the returned value of a function/methods - specially during the development of the program.

Never ask to the StackOverFlow community (and to any other) to write progams for you!

You question *"how do I get all elements from a scroll div?"* is so "loose". scroll div? The answer to this, independently to the "type of div" (and tag!) would be found below.

Your code seems to be no sense in order to do what you want. Why iterate from 0 to 10?

Look at this snipet. I think it will help you

```
const list = document.getElementsByClassName('md-virtual-repeat-scroller')[0];// if there is no intention to reassign it. Use [0] if you are sure it's the first element of this collection
let childs = list.getElementsByClassName("result__name"); // get only elements inside the first variable!
```

Use the iterator of the variable.

```
for(item of childs) 
{
 /*code*/ 
}
```

I am sure you will achieve your goals!

And never suggest us (Community) to code for you or even to resolve your problem. This sound very agressive! To you too! I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you Daniel : )